# How to get a value from a radio-buttons' collection

Tags: jquery, user-interface, radio-button, atk4

I was able to get the value from an input type=text with code like this:

`$salad_size    = $form->addField('line','salad');`



`$salad_button->js('click')->univ()->ajaxec(
                array(
                    $this->api->getDestinationURL(), 
                    'generate_salad'=>true,
                    'salad_size'=>$salad_size->js()->val(),
                ));`

Now I need to get a value from any out of three radio-buttons. This is the object construction:
`$salad_size = $form->addField('radio','salad_size')->setValueList(array('S'=>'Chica','M'=>'Mediana','L'=>'Grande'));`

I'd like to know which exactly is the method name to use instead of 'val()' (as it looks not to be the right one for radios).

I was unable to get the methods list from the API reference page [here](http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/ref). Any other source of avail methods?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried is(':checked') instead of val() ?

Comment: Solved!
`'salad_size'=>$salad_size->js()->find(":checked")->val(),`

...based on this response from another thread:
`$("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val();`

This is the resulting rendered code: 
`...$('#pidocomida_index_form_salad_size').find(':checked').val()`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [agiletoolkit radio button demo page](http://demo.atk4.com?t=14)

For the radio button it has the following example

```
$p=$this;
$values=array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female');

$f=$p->add('Form');
$f->addField('line','name');
$f->addField('radio','gender')
  ->setValueList($values)
  ->setNotNull();
$f->addSubmit();

if($f->isSubmitted()){
  $f->js()->univ()->alert($f->get('name').', you are a '.$values[$f->get('gender')])->execute();
}
```

Comment: I see from a question you posted on 14 Sep and linked with this example you already know about this demo page so maybe this wont help if you have already tried it this way.

Comment: Yes Trevor, I already knew that example but isn't applicable to my situation because it's applying the get() method on a form object, while I'm trying to grab a value from the $_GET array. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @fernandojmartin here is trying to put checkboxes into the grid, so he needs to collect data manually.